# Windows loginID help on Windows/Apache2.2 environment

Tags: apache2, cgi, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, ntlm

I really could use some help in solving what appears to be a trivial issue.  In summary, I want to know the Window's loginID for the user accessing a Perl .cgi running in Apache on a Windows environment.

Here's my basic Apache2 conf additions:

---- begin httpd.conf -----

```
...

LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
...
<IfModule mod_auth_sspi.c>
    <Location "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
        AuthName "A Protected Place"
        AuthType SSPI
        SSPIAuth On
        SSPIAuthoritative On
        #SSPIBasic On
        SSPIOfferBasic On
        #SSPIDomain On
        #SSPIBasicPreferred
        #SSPIUsernameCase lower
        require valid-user
    </Location>
</IfModule>
...
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
...
```

---- end httpd.conf -----

In addition, I've also enabled SSL on my machine using the excellent instructions at:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup.html#tsvn-serversetup-apache-7

The site above calls for loading the Apache module mod_auth.so, but I can't find it in my default Apache2 installation.  Also, As you can see, I've manually added the mod_auth_sspi-1.0.4-2.2.2 module to my Apache2 environment.

Now, when I try both **http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi** AND **https://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi**, I don't see anything in the way of a REMOTE_USER in the http/environment variables.  I know the SSL is working because the https call displays a ton of SSL variables.  Also, I don't have a requirement for SSL, but am only using it since the link above says it is required to get the Windows login info.

I would really appreciate any insight.  I am happy to share the httpd.conf file in full if that is helpful.  Basically, to reiterate, all I'm looking for is a way to capture the Windows loginID in my Perl .cgi on a Windows/Apache2.2 hosting environment.

Many many thanks in advance for everyone's help,

Saker Ghani

Answer (score 0):

This might not help too much, but I don't believe you need to do anything special to get this information.  I'm running an Apache 2.2 installation with mod_auth_sspi and I use the REMOTE_USER environment variable to successfully get the information you're looking for.  (For example, when I access one of the pages, REMOTE_USER is "MYDOMAIN\oeuftete".)

I don't use the SSPIOfferBasic option which is the only substantial configuration difference, but I don't think that would matter.  I also specify the options in the  directive and not in a separate  directive.

I guess what I'm saying is, based on what you've given, it *should* work.  So perhaps there's something else going on.

---

Edit:  Here's the basics of my httpd.conf.

```
LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /sotest "C:/Some/path/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/Some/path">
    Options ExecCGI

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "Foo"
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On

    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

And a short test.pl in that directory.

```
#!perl -T
#

use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

print $q->header;
print $q->start_html;
print $ENV{'REMOTE_USER'};
print $q->end_html;
```

Here's the resulting page from going to sotest/test.pl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
MYDOMAIN\oeuftete
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oeuftete, if it wouldn't be asking for too much, is there any way you could share your httpd.conf file with me?  That would be a huge help.  My email address is saker at ghani dot com.

Comment: Thanks oeuftete.  The code works, but only if I'm logged into the machine which is running Apache and the .cgi itself.  Can you get the above to work when accessing sotest/test.pl from a different machine?  In my case, I'm getting a "Authorization Required" on FF and an authentication prompt on IE.

Comment: It works for me on IE fine... if you're getting an authentication prompt in IE, then you probably aren't a valid user.  What does your apache error.log say when you get the prompt?

For FF, you need to log in with your domain information.  So in my example, user "MYDOMAIN\oeuftete" and the password.

Comment: In the comment above, a "valid user" in the IE example means you're logged on as a valid user on the same domain of the machine which is running your Apache installation.

Comment: oeuftete, I had to make one minor tweak on my httpd.conf and your code works beautifully.  I owe you one, at least!

Comment: You should let everyone know what the tweak was if you can to help someone else down the road.

Answer (score -1):

Not a windows programmer, so I'm not sure what a loginID is, but maybe
[Win32::LoginName and Win32::LookupAccountName](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32) will be of help?

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't do since Windows will run the .cgi as SYSTEM user and both of the above solutions can only return the parent user's identity.  In this case, we need the client browser to supply the Windows/NTLM loginID to Apache somehow, so that the .cgi can utilize this info.

Comment: Ah.  Yuck.  That seems like the kind of thing the browser shouldn't normally be transmitting to the server??